# Error faced while trying to do anomaly detection with R

Tags: r, anomaly-detection, tibbletime

I'm trying to use R Anomalize package to check the anomalies in our revenue,

I'm following the instructions from Quick start documentation below,
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/anomalize/vignettes/anomalize_quick_start_guide.html

In my case, I am trying to convert the data frame into a tibble time object as below,

```
library(anomalize)
library(tibble)
library(tibbletime)
library(tidyverse)

revenue <- read.csv(file = '../data/revenue.csv') %>%
  mutate(date = as.Date(date)) %>%
  as_tbl_time(index = date) %>%
  group_by(country_code, date) %>%
  summarise(count = sum(`total_revenue`, na.rm = TRUE))
```

This is how the tibble time object looks,

```
> revenue
# A time tibble: 807 x 3
# Index:  date
# Groups: country_code [39]
   country_code date       count
   <chr>        <date>     <dbl>
 1 AE           2020-09-01 4688.
 2 AE           2020-09-02 3054.
 3 AE           2020-09-03 3987.
 4 AE           2020-09-04 3337.
 5 AE           2020-09-05 2947.
 6 AE           2020-09-06 3597.
 7 AE           2020-09-07 3737.
 8 AE           2020-09-08 4187.
 9 AE           2020-09-09 3038.
10 AE           2020-09-10 3803.
# … with 797 more rows
```

But, when trying to do anomaly detection with below code,

```
revenue_anomalized <- revenue %>%
  time_decompose(count, merge = TRUE) %>%
  anomalize(remainder) %>%
  time_recompose()
```

I'm getting the following error,

> Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `nested.col`.
> x Problem with `mutate()` input `date`.
> x Only year, quarter, month, week, and day periods are allowed for an index of class Date
> ℹ Input `date` is `collapse_index(...)`.
> ℹ Input `nested.col` is `purrr::map(.x = data, .f = .f, target = count, ...)`.
> Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
> In addition: Warning messages:
> 1: Problem with `mutate()` input `nested.col`.
> ℹ can not calculate periodicity of 1 observation
> ℹ Input `nested.col` is `purrr::map(.x = data, .f = .f, target = count, ...)`. 
> 2: In xts::periodicity(idx) :
> can not calculate periodicity of 1 observation

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The "can not calculate periodicity of 1 observation" part of the error makes me think maybe one (or more) of your country codes only have a single observation? Perhaps try sticking a `filter(n() > 1)` after your `summarize`.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. it was the problem. Some of the countries are new and we didn't have periodic data. Thanks for the help.